# How do I fix java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program which utilizes OOP. The program I am creating is supposed to recruit applicants to a team. In my `Team.java`, I created a method which is supposed to accept members and add it to the team. This is a snippet of my code:

```
public int maxMembers;
public Member members[] = new Member[maxMembers];
public int memberCount = 0;

        public void addMember(Member newMember) {
            members[maxMembers] = newMember;
            memberCount++;
        }
```

I have tried this code but the line,

```
members[maxMembers] = newMember;
```

keeps throwing an error `java.lang.ArrayOutOfBoundsException: 2`

I have tried using a for loop in adding a new member but it does not do what I expected. Can anyone assist me in finding a solution?

Comment: Have you try 'members[memberCount] = newMember;' ! And what is value of maxMembers before creating 'new Member' ? Can you adapt your question ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign `maxMembers` a value in the first line, otherwise your array will have 0 elements.

```
public int maxMembers = 10;
```

Comment: I see. But I'm following a UML class diagram given to me and in it, there was not a value indicated to `maxMembers`. I will still try this nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you did not initialize the variable `maxMembers`.Also, in the code, the line `members[maxMembers] = newMember;` would always put your entry in the end of the array, I think thats not the intended use of your method, `public void addMember(Member newMember)`
 Rewriting your method would look like,

```
        public int maxMembers=somePositiveInteger;
        public Member members[] = new Member[maxMembers];
        public int memberCount = 0;

        public void addMember(Member newMember) {
            members[memberCount] = newMember;//here
            memberCount++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the array with a value so that number of elements in array can be decided.